# Boolean conditions in console.log() statement

Tags: javascript, console.log

I've just noticed that you can put boolean expressions within console.log e.g. `console.log("hey" || 2)` where in this case`hey` would be printed out to the console window.

I'm not 100% sure exactly how `console.log` determines what to print when there is a condition within it.

Comment: If the expression at the left side of || resolves to something truthy, it will get printed, if not the expression on the right side gets printed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a concept of [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values in JavaScript. Non empty string is considered *truthy* value, so `"hey"` evaluates to `true` and is printed, because the part after `||` is not evaluated in that case.

In general *truthy* are all values that are not `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, or `NaN`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) defines evaluation of OR expressions as follows:

> Logical OR (`||`) `expr1 || expr2`: Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to
>   true; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values,
>   `||` returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns
>   false.

So by this logic `console.log()` prints first truthy expression in your statement. If you were to try `console.log(null || 2)`, then `2` would be printed out.

Answer (score 1):

if the a  value is falsy(false, undefined, 0, NaN and "") then it will take the right side value.else it will get print the a itself.

```
var a = null;

console.log(a || 10); //10 will print
```

or

```
var a = 20;

console.log(a || 10);//20 will print
```

Comment: Not quite - It's not that it's a null but that it's considered falsy. `false`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN` and `""` is also considered falsy and would in this case cause the right side to be printed

Answer (score 0):

Most simply put, when a logical operator exists in the expression, it will try to evaluate the whole expression - and since "||" means "or", when "hey" is evaluated, it returns `true`, hence there is no need to evaluate the expression further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me try to add my two cents to Bohuslav's great explanation... If you want to see a good practical example, check out this exercise from the book [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#c_0irNU0p0MR):

"FizzBuzz

Write a program that uses console.log to print all the numbers from 1 to 100, with two exceptions. For numbers divisible by 3, print "Fizz" instead of the number, and for numbers divisible by 5 (and not 3), print "Buzz" instead.

When you have that working, modify your program to print "FizzBuzz", for numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 (and still print "Fizz" or "Buzz" for numbers divisible by only one of those)."

And the [solution](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#2.2):

```js
for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
    var output = "";
    if (n % 3 == 0)
        output += "Fizz";
    if (n % 5 == 0)
        output += "Buzz";
    console.log(output || n);
}
```

Here the variable `output` is an empty string, so the console log won't print it, as empty strings are falsy; but as soon as "Fizz" or "Buzz" is added to its value, it becomes truthy and gets printed out instead of `n`.

Note that it wouldn't work the other way around with: `console.log(n || output)`. As `n` is the first expression and always true, it will be printed every time and `output` will be ignored.